# Gerar números aleatórios em Python sem repetir

Tags: python, python-2.7, lista, números-aleatórios

Tenho a seguinte situação:

Possuo um vetor com 4 índices. Em cada índice é gerado um valor aleatório de 0 até 100.

Possuo um código que faz isso perfeitamente, porém, as vezes os números se repetem.

Abaixo o código:

---

```
from random import randint

AP_X = [randint(0, 100), randint(0, 100), randint(0, 100), randint(0, 100)]
print AP_X
```

---

Desejo que **NUNCA** sejam gerados números repetidos. Por exemplo: `[4,4,6,7]`

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para você sortear **4** valores de dentro do intervalo **[0, 100]**, sem repetições, você precisa implementar o **range(0, 101)**, utilizando o método **[sample](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/random.html#random.sample)** da biblioteca **[random](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/random.html)**.

Então, o código pode ser montado da seguinte forma:

```
from random import sample

sorteados = sample(range(0, 101), 4)
print(sorteados)
```

Desta forma podemos sortear **4** valores dentre o **range(0, 101)** sem repetições.

Answer (score 14):

```
import random
result = random.sample(range(0,100), 4)
```

Comment: Obrigado! Funcionou corretamente.

Answer (score 7):

Basta verificar se o valor sorteado já não pertence à lista e, se pertencer, sorteie outro. Algo como:

```
result = []
while len(result) != 4:
    r = randint(0, 100)
    if r not in result:
        result.append(r)
```

Desta forma o código é executado até que a lista tenha 4 elementos e só é inserido um novo quando o mesmo já não estiver na lista.

Comment: Obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Por que não guardar os valores em um set e depois transformá-la em uma lista?

Comment: @GermanoBarcelos porque assim você não garante que serão 4 valores distintos

Answer (score -1):

Se vocês estiverem trabalhando com dicionários no python:

```
aleatorio = randint(1, 6)
test = NomeDict.values()

if aleatorio not in test:
    NomeDict.update({chave: valor})
```

Comment: Não faz sentido como resposta, o autor da pergunta apenas quer uma lista de quatro números aleatórios entre zero e cem que não se repitam ou seja `random.sample(range(0,100), 4)`.