# Verificar se número ja contem na linha e coluna

Tags: python

Boa noite, preciso fazer um sudoku, e a primeira parte é imprimir uma matriz com número aleatórios de 1 a 9 e verificar se esse número já tem na linha e coluna. Eu fiz isso:

```
import random
matriz = []
for i in range(9):
    linha = []
    for j in range(9):
        aleatorio = random.randint(1, 9)
        if aleatorio != i and aleatorio != j:
            linha.append(aleatorio)
        matriz.append(linha)

for i in range(9):
    print(matriz[i])
```

Mas nao funciona, quando dou print a matriz as vezes fica com uma linha e coluna a menos ou a mais, e os numeros se repetem. Alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: Você está tentando gerar uma tabela completa com números aleatórios? Tem certeza de que isso irá funcionar? Não estou afirmando, mas acredito que em Sudoku, só porque um número pode ser inserido em determinada célula, não significa que ele deve ser inserido. Muitas vezes você pode acabar trancando a tabela com essas ações.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifica se o número já existe na lista antes de adicionar, assim vc evita dele se repetir. E usuando o while faz com que ele repita até preencher a lista.

Fonte do código: [Link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/195422/gerar-n%C3%BAmeros-aleat%C3%B3rios-em-python-sem-repetir)

```
result = []
while len(result) != 4:
    r = randint(0, 100)
    if r not in result:
        result.append(r)
```